# How to exit from an sql script in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We have a requirement to call the pl/sql stored procedure from an sql script. we are reading the out `variable(v_return_code)` from a stored procedure and we need to exit from sql/script based on out `variable(v_return_code)`. But in our sql script we are not using any PL/SQL(procedural language).How can we exit from sql script using sql statments only ?.

Sql script code snippet:

```
VARIABLE  v_return_code number;
EXECUTE splits(:v_return_code);
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. An "sql script" is a script, in a scripting language, that includes some SQL statements. To exit from your script, you must use commands of the scripting language, NOT SQL statements. So: What do you mean by "sql script"? Do you mean an SQL\*Plus script? A UNIX shell script? Something else? (I will just guess you mean a SQL\*Plus script, but will wait for your confirmation.)

Comment: I think you are running a SQL*Plus script. If that is the case, you could use `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE` and raise an exception from stored procedure for the cases that would return undesired return code.

Comment: Do you mean you want the caller (e.g. shell) to see the value set by your procedure as the overall exit code from SQL\*Plus? So if your procedure set the variable to 7, then in a shell script that called `sqlplus @script` you could do `echo $?` and see the value 7? That is certainly possible, up to a point. Or do you want to decide whether or not to exit  based on the value - so later statements in the script are not run?

Comment: that is splits.sql script(SQL*Plus script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SQL*Plus script add an exit command:

```
VARIABLE  v_return_code number;
EXECUTE splits(:v_return_code);
exit :v_return_code
```

Then you can access the return code from your calling environment, for example in unix you could

```
echo $?
```

while in windows you could

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

to see the value returned.

Comment: I've done that with substitution variables (even creating one via `new_value`), but I didn't know you could use a bind variable directly there. Nice. However, you're still restricted in the values you can usefully use; ["The range of operating system return codes is also restricted on some operating systems"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve023.htm#SQPUG044), and on Unix at least they wrap round to zero, so `exit 256` will end up with `$?` of zero, 257 becomes 1, etc. It might not matter for the range of possible values produced by the OP's procedure though.